# i am getting the following error MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS Application log on my server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

> TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code
>   0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check
>   for previous errors. Cannot find object or property.
>
> TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code
>   0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. Cannot find object or
>   property.
>
> Initializing the FallBack certificate failed with error code: 1,
>   state: 20, error number: 0.

From comments:

> Log Name: Application Source: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS Date: 2016-06-01
>   9:36:25 AM Event ID: 17204 Task Category: Server Level: Error
>   Keywords: Classic User: N/A Computer: XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXX Description:
>   FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
>   E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1. OS error: 21(The device is not ready.).
>
> Log Name: Application Source: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS Date: 2016-06-01
>   9:36:25 AM Event ID: 17204 Task Category: Server Level: Error
>   Keywords: Classic User: N/A Computer: xxxx.x..xxx Description:
>   FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
>   E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf
>   for file number 1. OS error: 21(The device is not ready.).
>
> Log Name: Application Source: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS Date: 2016-06-01
>   9:36:25 AM Event ID: 17207 Task Category: Server Level: Error
>   Keywords: Classic User: N/A Computer: XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXX
>   Description: FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The
>   system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or
>   opening file
>   'E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf'.
>   Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the
>   operation.

Comment: Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
Date:          2016-06-01 9:36:25 AM
Event ID:      17204
Task Category: Server
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXX
Description:
FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 21(The device is not ready.).

Comment: Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
Date:          2016-06-01 9:36:25 AM
Event ID:      17204
Task Category: Server
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      xxxx.x..xxx
Description:
FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 21(The device is not ready.).

Comment: Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
Date:          2016-06-01 9:36:25 AM
Event ID:      17207
Task Category: Server
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXX
Description:
FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.

Comment: I have the above error in my Application log on one of my server Pleae any one experiencing the same issue any fix for this

Comment: Similar question/answer: http://serverfault.com/a/509514/7309

Comment: You can find the solution in the following link: https://blog.brankovucinec.com/2015/04/08/mssql-server-not-starting-after-fresh-installation/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is telling you it can't find some of your system databases (model and MSDB).

Verify that the files exist and that SQL Server has permission to access them.  SQL is looking in `E:\sql12_main_t.obj.x86Release\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj`, and that's where they should be.

If they're not there, restore them from backup.  (Did someone delete them?)